# Find lim: $x_n=\dfrac{1+\frac12+...+\frac1{2^n}}{1+\frac14+...+\frac1{4^n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find limit: $x_n=\dfrac{1+\frac12+...+\frac1{2^n}}{1+\frac14+...+\frac1{4^n}}$

as $n \rightarrow \infty$

My "intuition" says that it should be $\frac34$ but I don't know how to proove it with rigour.

Comment: Do you know a [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) for finding the sums in numerator and denominator explicitly?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Derivation

Comment: Yes, I can tell it's a geometric series. But then, in the proof, is it ok to say "lim when n → infty 0.5^(n+1) = 0" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By induction you can prove the following formula for the sum of terms of a geometric progression:
$$a + ar + ar^2 + ... + ar^n = {a - ar^{n+1} \over 1 - r}$$
So you can apply this in the numerator with $a = 1, r = {1 \over 2}$, and in the denominator with $a = 1, r = {1 \over 4}$. You obtain
$$x_n = {1 - {1 \over 2^{n+1}} \over 1 - {1 \over 2}} \times {1 - {1 \over 4} \over 1 - {1 \over 4^{n+1}}}$$
$$= {3 \over 2} {1 - {1 \over 2^{n+1}} \over 1 - {1 \over 4^{n+1}}}$$
Now take limits as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:have a look at $\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{n}}}{1+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{4^{n}}}\times\frac{2-1}{4-1}=\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)\left(2-1\right)}{\left(1+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{4^{n}}\right)\left(4-1\right)}$ You will 'loose' quite some terms.

Comment: What does the x symbol represent?

Comment: multiplication. You multiply by (2-1)/(4-1)=1/3. If you have the answer then you restore that by multiplying by 3.

Comment: I can't see why that trick is any good, but I would be glad to understand why it makes the calculation easier.

Comment: $\left(2^{0}+2^{-1}+\cdots2^{-n}\right)\left(2-1\right)=\left(2^{1}+2^{0}+\cdots2^{-n+1}\right)-\left(2^{0}+2^{-1}+\cdots2^{-n}\right)=2-2^{-n}$ In the denominator you do the same with $4$ instead of $2$. The fraction becomes definitely more friendly and easyer to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Geometric series

$$\sum_{n=k}^m r^n=r^k\frac{(r^{m+1}-1)}{r-1}$$

and then a little arithmetic of limits:

$$x_n=\frac{\frac{1-\frac1{2^n}}{1-\frac12}}{\frac{1-\frac1{4^n}}{1-\frac14}}=\frac{2-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}}{\frac{4-\frac{1}{4^{n-1}}}{3}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac{2-0}{\frac{4-0}3}=\frac32$$